# How to type the Arara logo?

Tags: fun, logos

I may deserve a silly duck for this. I have successfully implemented the comfy arara (from Paulo Cereda) system for automating the typesetting steps of my master thesis, and I want to cite it in the colophon.

I saw the logo in the guides' text, but I did not manage to find out what its command is (I tried `\arara` with no avail). What is such command?

Comment: The distribution has a `logos` directory. Tha  parrot lone is `bird.pdf`.

Comment: @Bernard yeah, I looked at that but I believe it is not the one used in the text, as it looks in a command form (like \LaTeX). I can tell this because in the GitHub logo there is an actual arara, while in the text logo there is not

Comment: I don't know what's on GitHud, but  in the manual, it is mainly `bird.pdf` which is used, with different scalings.

Comment: I’m sure you’re not a silly duck, but I do like the idea of a silly duck badge to go with our many other badges!  Lines 77–78 of `arara.sty` (in the documentation folder) seem to be what you want.

Comment: Try this: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\marmot[teeth,whiskers,blush]}
\end{document}` ;-)

Comment: @Thérèse We could ask to dr. Cereda himself, I have few doubts he will disagree. Above all, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\arara` command and its color are defined in `arara.sty` (in the documentation folder):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{araracolour}{rgb}{0, 0.72, 0.28}
\newcommand{\araratext}[1]{{\normalfont\fontfamily{fco}\selectfont\color{araracolour}\bfseries#1}}% Comfortaa-Bold
\newcommand*\arara{\araratext{ar\kern-.03emar\kern-.03ema}}
\begin{document}
\arara
\end{document}
```

https://imgur.com seems to have the flu today, because people are having trouble uploading screenshots, but if you compile the above with `pdflatex`, you’ll see the text of the logo used in the manual. The lovely bird, as Bernard comments, is in the `logos` directory.

Comment: That's neat! I didn't look that throughoutly into the style file, next time it won't happen.